# Boost.Spirit is not parsing whole input

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I have a boost::spirit::qi rules:

```
auto dquote = qi::char_('\"');
auto comma = qi::char_(',');
auto newline = qi::char_('\n');
auto nonEscaped = *(qi::char_ - newline - comma - dquote);
auto escaped = *qi::blank >> dquote >> *((qi::char_ - dquote) | (dquote >> dquote)) >> dquote >> *qi::blank;
auto field = nonEscaped | escaped;
```

When I try to parse an input:

```
string input(" \"e\"\"e\" ");
qi::phrase_parse(begin(input), end(input), field, qi::char_('\r'));
```

The input is not fully matched by the `escaped` rule, but only the `nonEscaped` rule is applied. So only the first space is matched. How do I convince spirit to parse whole input or to parse as much as possible?

When I change the order of variants in the `field` rule to the following, then it works. But is that the right solution?

```
auto field = escaped | nonEscaped;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, reordering is the right solution.

Boost Spirit generates what's known as `LL parsers`, which means

> It parses the input from Left to right, and constructs a [Leftmost derivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Derivations_and_syntax_trees) of the sentence (hence LL, compared with LR parser)

In simple words, it matches the first possible token and doesn't do backtracking *unless* the rule fails. You could 'assert' a post-condition of sorts at the end of the `nonEscaped` rule, see

- [qi::eps(false)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/eps.html)
- [& parser operator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/and_predicate.html) (zero-width lookahead)
- [! parser operator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/not_predicate.html) (zero-width *negative* lookahead)
- [- parser operator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/difference.html)

Using Semantic Actions:

- assigning to `_pass` in semantic actions
- use a semantic action function object, returning `bool` (false to fail)

However, in practice this will lead to suboptimal parsers (unnecessary backtracking, e.g.)

HTH